# Android Studio Code Style - Excluding fields

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm using standard Android coding style rules in Android Studio (for SEO, Intellij Idea), but I'd like to save fields from being rearranged. I currently have

`Code Style -> Java -> Blank lines -> Minimum Blank lines around field = 0`

Every time Studio formats fields it groups everything in a *field blob*:

```
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

I'd like to keep my fields grouped as I like, i.e.

```
field1
field2

field3
field4
field5
```

Is there some way to exclude certain types from being formatted/rearranged?

Thank you